# MVC partial views, and complex Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

I'm trying to populating a nested Model

The model looks something like this

```
public Layout {
   public List<Record> Records {get;set;}
}

public Record {
   public List<PlaceHolder> PlaceHolders {get;set;}
}

public PlaceHolder {
   public string Label {get;set;}
}
```

When my form posts, using fiddler, I see that the values coming down with keys in the format

```
Records.Index = 0
Records.PlaceHolders.Index = 0
Records[0].PlaceHolders[0].Label = foo
Records.Index = 0
Records.PlaceHolders.Index = 1
Records[0].PlaceHolders[1].Label = bar
Records.Index = 1
Records.PlaceHolders.Index = 1
Records[1].PlaceHolders[1].Label = boo
...
```

A lot of these KeyNames I had to generate myself using partial views, padding a TemplateInfo with the HtmlFieldPrefix set.

When I look at my save controller, the Layout is only partially populated.  It has all it's Records in the Records property.  But none of the Records contain PlaceHolders.

What is wrong with my post keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I need these lines

```
Records.PlaceHolders.Index = 0
```

To have the Record's Index, like so

```
Records[1].PlaceHolders.Index = 0
```